# copy worksheet and choosing where to put new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code which does almost exactly what I need it to do:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

The issue is that the copied worksheet always goes to the end of the workbook, and I want to place it after a particular tab.

I think the answer is probably excruciatingly simple, but I'd really appreciate your help as I'm a newbie.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("someSheetName")
```